# Bash IFS ignores part of string

Tags: bash

I store the output of ssh command that I run from bash in a variable and I'am trying to parse it and get the last value using IFS but it keeps ignoring the part that comes from Qt app.
Here is what I have done:

```
#!/bin/bash
results=$(ssh remote 'dbus-send --system --print-reply --type=method_call --dest=com.something.SomeApp /SomeApp com.something.SomeApp.status' 2>&1)
echo $results
IFS=$' ' # space is set as delimiter
read -ra ADDR <<< "$results" # results are read into an array as tokens separated by IFS
for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do # access each element of array
    printf '%s\n' "$i"
done
```

Output:

```
method return time=1570704023.543658 sender=:1.13063 -> destination=:1.14063 serial=5451 reply_serial=2 string "Idle"
method
return
time=1570700627.183948
sender=:1.13063
->
destination=:1.13308
serial=1183
reply_serial=2
```

It's missing:
`string` and `"Idle"`.

If I copy the output that I get in terminal, paste it in bash script and run IFS on it like this it works:

```
#!/bin/bash
manual="method return time=1570703114.770058 sender=:1.13063 -> destination=:1.13859 serial=4306 reply_serial=2 string "Idle""
IFS=$' ' # space is set as delimiter
read -ra ADDR <<< "$manual"
for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do
    printf '%s\n' "$i"
done
```

Is there a hidden symbol that prevents IFS to read all string and how can I achieve my goal to get the whole string to array?

Comment: Can you `printf '%q\n' "$results"` to see if it uses a tab or other exotic delimiter? Anyway you could try the default `IFS=$' \t\n'`.

Comment: results=$(ssh remote 'dbus-send --system --print-reply --type=method_call --dest=com.something.SomeApp /SomeApp com.something.SomeApp.status' 2>&1 | xargs)

Comment: Thanks @LéaGris and @Šerg for yore help.
Using @LéaGris advice I can verify that there is the special `\n` new line character:
`...reply_serial=2\n   string "Idle"'`.
And using @Šerg advice I get the whole string to array which is what I wanted.
Now I just want to find out why this `| xargs` works, but this I guess is a job Google can do for me.